# STConcaveHull with MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concave-hull

MS SQL Server supports the STConvexHull function but not the STConcaveHull function.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stconvexhull-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16
Is there any way I can calculate the concave hull for a set of points using MS SQL Server?